# Can my client use my bing maps key?

Tags: c#, uwp, bing-maps

I am developing an uwp app that uses the map control for a client. The client will publish this app under their microsoft account. My question is this.
Do they have to create their own key for bing maps associated with their account or they can use another valid key(say mine).

In other words, does every uwp app that uses maps have to have a different bing maps key created under the microsoft account of the publisher, or it can use any valid key.

Comment: As I understand (I might be wrong), your client would then be using your credentials, hence Microsoft would charge YOU for the costs of the usage, if any exists.

Comment: For each project, you should have a unique key which ties back to your client. While in testing use your own, thats fine, but once you pass the ownership over you need to make sure everything they client needs is in there with no connection to yourself.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath Yes Microsoft would be charging me, this is understood and it is ok. It is part of the service I want to offer. I am asking if it is possible .

Comment: If the client is a company, make them register their own key; if the client is any Windows user anywhere in the world who happens to download your app,  then yes it's obviously possible

Comment: @Takarii In the case that the client doesn't want to concern themselves with bing maps account management and they are prepared to pay me any cost incurred by microsoft. My question is if it is legal and possible to publish an app under one account, and use the bing maps key of another account.

Comment: @Corcus legal? absolutely. A good idea? not at all. Consider if you were ever to go out of business, their link to the key would vanish along with it. Better practice would be to set up all the nessecary parts and pass these accounts over to the client. They may not want to set it up themselves, and thats fine, but you should absolutely set it up such that you can walk away and have nothing more to do with it if need be.

Comment: @Corcus You can use whatever keys you like inside the application itself, microsoft won't prevent you from doing anything like that. If the application is a custom build specifically for the client though, it would be ill advised to maintain a direct connection to the project, except where you are contracted to maintain the code as time goes on.

Comment: @Takarii thanks for your comments. Please form them into an answer (with references if you have any) and  I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each project you create that requires the services of an API (google, microsoft, icloud etc) should really be set up with their own accounts and authorisation keys.

There is nothing stopping you from using the same account over multiple projects. Consider, if you will, a large company that produces many software products that all use google maps. Rather than an individual account for each project, along with a unique key, you might have a single account with multiple authorisation keys (one for each project). While you should really create seperate keys for each application, you can indeed use the same key over all applications. Legally there is nothing preventing you from publishing an application under a different account to the one you used to generate any authorisation keys.

***On the subject of maintaining this for your client:***

If the product is a custom build specifically for your client, then burden of maintaining the account to which the keys are bound should really fall on the client directly once you have finished. By all means, set the accounts up for them and provide the credentials for use once you are done (I wouldn't expect any clients to do this themselves).

Maintaining a direct link to the project once it is finished could turn out badly for either you or the client.

Consider the following scenarios

1) You, for whatever reason, fall out with the client.

2) You, for whatever reason, are no longer able to maintain the account (eg. financial, incapacitation, retirement etc)

In these cases, the client could potentially lose a critical component of their product and as a result legal action could be taken against you to recoup any loss of earnings. This is why it is far safer and a much better idea to pass over all accounts and details of the project to the client so that they can maintain it themselves, making sure to document things properly so they can do so.

So back to your initial questions.

Can you use a key from an account that is different to the publishing account within the application? **Absolutely.**

Is it legal?  **Yes.**

Should you the developers personal/company account to maintain it for the client? **Not really**, but that doesn't mean it can't/shouldn't be done (given the right circumstances.

Comment: In addition to this, you can also email the Bing Maps licensing team at maplic@microsoft.com and they can assist you with any licensing or legal related question on Bing Maps.